# A notion of support for nonabelian infinite groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, set-theory, infinite-combinatorics

Every Abelian group $G$ of infinite size $\kappa$ embeds into a product $\bigoplus_{\alpha<\kappa}G_\alpha$ of countable (divisible) groups. By looking at the map $s$ that sends a group element $g\in G$ to the support of its copy in $\bigoplus_{\alpha<\kappa}G_\alpha$, we obtain a map $s:G\rightarrow[\kappa]^{<\omega}$ satisfying the two:

1. The map $s$ is countable-to-one;
2. For all $g,h\in G$, $s(g) \mathbin\triangle s(h)\subseteq s(g+h)\subseteq s(g)\cup s(h)$.

In this [paper](https://doi.org/10.1112/mtk.12200) with Feldman, a group $G$ admitting such a map is called *well-behaved*.

A second example of a well-behaved group is a free (nonabelian) group with $\kappa$ generators. This is witnessed by the map that sends any word to its set of letters.

I would like to raise the following questions:

1. Is there an example of an infinite group that is not well-behaved?
2. Is $S_\infty$ well-behaved?
3. Does the continuum hypothesis (CH) imply that all groups of size $\aleph_1$ are well-behaved?

Comment: What do you denote $S_\infty$?

Comment: Here, $S_\infty$ stands for the group of bijections of the natural numbers, and the group operation is composition.

Comment: Here $S_\infty$ must be $\mathrm{Sym}(\mathbf N)$ rather than the finitary one, because the finitary one, being countable, is obviously well-behaved in this sense. (Correct me if I misunderstood.)

Comment: Yes, countable groups are well-behaved, as witnessed by a constant map.

Comment: Some observations that slightly simplify the definition (at least for me): Define a new map $s'$ by $s'(g) = s(g) \setminus s(1)$. Then $s'$ satisfies 1 and 2 and additionally $s'(1) = \emptyset$. Therefore we can assume $s(1) = \emptyset$. Then also $s(g) \mathbin\triangle s(g^{-1}) \subset s(1) = \emptyset$, so $s(g) = s(g^{-1})$. Given $s(g) = s(g^{-1})$, condition 2 simplifies to just $s(gh) \subset s(g) \cup s(h)$. So, in summary, we want a countable-to-one map $s:G \to [\kappa]^{<\omega}$ such that $s(1) = \emptyset$, $s(g^{-1}) = s(g)$, and $s(g h) \subset s(g) \cup s(h)$.

Comment: It seems reasonable to guess that any such group $G$ has a map $f:G \to \operatorname{FSym}(\kappa)$ such that $\ker f$ is countable and $s(g) = \operatorname{supp}(f(g))$. This would answer all three questions (yes, no, no).

Comment: Hmm, on second thought, that doesn't seem to cover the case of direct sums of abelian groups, as there are elements with singleton support.

Comment: @SeanEberhard thanks (this was my guess too)... I'm also not fond of this notation "$\infty$" which tends to ignore the fact, discovered by Cantor a while ago, that there are several infinite cardinals.

Answer (score 4):

This is basically a long comment. If $S_\infty$ is well-behaved, then any map witnessing this must be somewhat degenerate and there is no "elementary way" to construct such a map.

Specifically, we will see that under $\mathrm{ZF}+\mathrm{DC}+{}$"all sets of reals have the Baire property",  $S_\infty$ is not well-behaved.

So suppose toward a contradiction that $S_\infty$ is well-behaved and $s\colon S_\infty\rightarrow [X]^{<\omega}$ witnesses this for some set $X$. We can assume additionally that if $g, h\in S_\infty$ differ at only finitely many places then $s(g)=s(h)$.  $S_\infty$ becomes a Polish space when equipped with basic open sets of the form $\{x\in S_\infty\mid t\subseteq x\}$ for $t$ finite.  Let $A_n$ be the elements of $S_\infty$ with $\vert s(g)\vert= n$ and note that not all $A_n$ can be meager, so pick some $n$ with $A_n$ nonmeager. As membership in $A_n$ depends only on the tail and $A_n$ has the Baire property, $A_n$ must in fact be comeager.  Let $M$ be the transitive collapse of a countable elementary substructure containing $s$ of a suitable $V_\alpha$. We will look at Cohen forcing, but the version which forces with the basic open sets of $S_\infty$ instead of the Baire space. It follows that for all $c$ Cohen over $M$, we have $c\in A_n$. Moreover, if $c, d$ are mutually Cohen over $M$ then $c\circ d$ is Cohen over $M$ as well, hence $c\circ d\in A_n$. The combinatorics of this cannot work out, here is one way to see it:

We will find two mutually Cohen generics $c, d$ over $M$ with $s(c), s(d)$ disjoint. This is impossible as we would have $s(c\circ d)=s(c)\cup s(d)$, but the lhs has size $n$ and the rhs has size $2n$ (and $n>0$).

Using the infinite Ramsey theorem, any infinite sequence of elements of $A_n$ can be thinned out to an infinite sequence whose supports form a $\Delta$-system. Let $(c_n)_{n<\omega}$ be a sequence of finitely mutually Cohen reals over $M$ so that

- $s(c_n)\neq s(c_m)$ for $n\neq m<\omega$
- $\{s(c_n)\mid n<\omega\}$ is a $\Delta$-system with root $R$ and
- $\vert R\vert$ is as small as possible given the other constraints.

The first bullet point can be arranged as $s$ is countable-to-one. We are done if we can show $R=\emptyset$, so assume otherwise. We will construct a sequence as above with root of smaller size. Consider $(d_n)_{n<\omega}$ where $d_n=c_{2n}\circ c_{2n+1}$ and thin out to a sequence $(d_{k_n})_{n<\omega}$ so that $\{s(d_{k_n})\mid n<\omega\}$ is a $\Delta$-system with root $R'$. As $s(c_{2n})\triangle s(c_{2n+1})\subseteq s(d_n)$, we have that $s(d_n)$ contains "two leafs" of the $\Delta$-system $\{s(c_n)\mid n<\omega\}$. Hence $\vert s(d_n)\cap s(d_m)\vert<\vert R\vert$ for all $n\neq m<\omega$ and consequently $\vert R'\vert<\vert R\vert$, contradiction.

Of course, this does not settle whether $S_\infty$ is well-behaved under $\mathrm{ZFC}$. The same argument should work for $(\mathbb R, +)$ which is well-behaved as soon as there is a Hamel basis.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Andreas. This is cool indeed. However, the question comes from anti-Ramsey problems, so the context is ZFC.

Comment: Thank you, 'saf! Yes, I assumed you are interested in ZFC results, but maybe knowing this obstruction is useful if somebody tries to construct a support for $S_\infty$ :)